# How create a geojson file dinamically from database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to create a geojson file dinamically extracting data from database.

And when geojson is created parse to inputStream to store it in a path with fileManager.

I would like load from database an have this scheme. Features contains an array of features and each feature contains an id, properties object with values and a geometry field that contains an array.

This is how to should be loaded from database: (Scheme 1)

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "AFG",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [...]
        }
    }]
}
```

I have two problems:

- When I make the request from postman show me my geojson scheme like this: (Scheme 2)

  ```
  [{
      "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [...],
          "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "table_id": 1,
      "properties": {
          "name": "Afghanistan"
      }
  }]
  ```

And when download file store it on folderPath with fileManager look like this: (Scheme 3)

```
[{
    geometry = {
        coordinates = []
        type = Polygon
    },
    type = Feature,
    table_id = 1,
    properties = {
        name = Afghanistan
    }
}]
```

So my problems are:

- How can load from database each feature and show like scheme 1??
- Why when store the file replace `:` by `=`???
- If I work with huge files how can create the file and not use a lot of memory???

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
public List<Object> getGeoJsonFromTable(String nameTable) {
    String SQL = "SELECT table_id, CAST(properties AS text) as properties, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as geometry FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";               
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL);

    JSONObject geojson = new JSONObject();
    geojson.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("type", "Feature");
        jsonObject.put("table_id", result.get(i).get("table_id") );
        jsonObject.put("geometry",  serializeProperty( result.get(i).get("geometry").toString() ) );
        jsonObject.put("properties", serializeProperty( result.get(i).get("properties").toString() ) );
        json.put(jsonObject);
    }
    geojson.put("feautures", json);
    List<Object> gson = json.toList();

    String fileName = nameTable + "_" + String.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()) + ".geojson";
    Path folderPath = Paths.get(ValidationUtil.initializeField(null, ""));
    String fileNewPath = folderPath.resolve(fileName).toString();
    try {
        fileManager.getFileStore().saveFile(new ByteArrayInputStream( gson.toString().getBytes("UTF-8") ), fileNewPath);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("ERROR: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return gson;
}
```

SOLUTION:

I've resolved how to create a geojson file from database, but I would like to do it with a better implementation. How can do it with a better implementation??

```
public String getGeoJsonFromTable(String nameTable) {
    String SQL = "SELECT table_id, CAST(properties AS text) as properties, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as geometry FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";               
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL);

    JSONObject geojson = new JSONObject();
    geojson.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("type", "Feature");
        jsonObject.put("id", result.get(i).get("table_id") );
        jsonObject.put("geometry",  serializeProperty( result.get(i).get("geometry").toString() ) );
        jsonObject.put("properties", serializeProperty( result.get(i).get("properties").toString() ) );
        json.put(jsonObject);
    }
    geojson.put("feautures", json);

    String fileName = nameTable + "_" + String.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()) + ".geojson";
    Path folderPath = Paths.get(ValidationUtil.initializeField(null, ""));
    String fileNewPath = folderPath.resolve(fileName).toString();
    try {
        fileManager.getFileStore().saveFile(new ByteArrayInputStream( geojson.toString().getBytes("UTF-8") ), fileNewPath);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("ERROR: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return geojson.toString();
}
```